# How to split a library and its plugins among npm packages?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

Im working on a JavaScript library and I want future users to be able to pick and choose the plugins they want to add to their project among with the main library. I'm having few issues with modules and webpack. I'm writing pseudo code to give an idea of how the code is organized.

My index.js for the main library looks like this:

```
import ClassA from "./classA";
import ClassB from "./classB";

export default class MyLib { 
    .....
}
export { ClassA, ClassB }
```

I can easily output the library with webpack:

```
output: {
     path: ...
     filename: 'mylib.min.js',
     library: "MyLib", 
     libraryTarget: "umd"
}
```

To be able to choose which plugins to add, I'm creating different npm packages (one for each plugin), adding MyLib as an external dependency and then doing:

```
import {ClassA, ClassB} from "MyLib";


class PluginA extends ClassB {
   constructor() {
      this.test = new ClassA();
   }
}
```

This works perfectly but, when "compiling" PluginA, webpack would include MyLib in the final js file for PluginA. If I want to include multiple plugins the code would end up with multiple copies of the main lib.

My final goal is to organize the code in such a way that can be easily installed with the following npm commands without having duplicated code everywhere:

```
npm install MyLib
npm install MyLib-PluginA
npm install MyLib-PluginB
```

Of course, one obvious solution would be to not use webpack for the plugins but I'd like to keep this option as the last resource in case nothing else works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging into webpack documentation, I've found a solution that uses webpack's externals.

From webpack documentation:

> The externals configuration option provides a way of excluding dependencies from the output bundles.

I've just added the following lines to the webpack's configuration for the plugin:

```
module.exports = {
    ...,
    externals: {
        mylib: { 
            commonjs: 'MyLib',
            commonjs2: 'MyLib',
            amd: 'MyLib',
            root: 'MyLib'
        }
    }
};
```

Webpack documentation: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend using webpack to build your plugins/library. Rather, I'd let the consumer of the library decide on their own bundler. Your best step for the library should just be transpilation (if needed) of any intermediate code like babel-featured JS or TypeScript into something that can be safely `require`'d by node.

In addition, each plugin ought to have `MyLib` as a `peerDependency` instead of a regular dependency. That will make sure that `MyLib` doesn't get nested inside of the plugin's `node_modules` and will thus avoid duplicates being bundled. The plugins could in addition has `MyLib` as a `devDependency` for the sake of unit tests, but the important bit is that it's never a regular `dependency`.

Comment: not sure about using just babel instead webpack yet but the suggestion about peerDependecies is super important! thanks a lot!

Comment: This is definitely the way to go.  After all, when you install your project's dependencies, imagine if a bunch of them used Webpack, others used Rollup, some used Parcel, etc.  Trying to configure it all would be a nightmare.  Best to just supply your library in a standard format (possibly using a transpiler if you want to target a newer JS version than is standard) and let the consumer of the libraries (i.e. the end user application) decide whether to use Webpack or an alternative.  This is, after all, what most other libraries already do!